# Synergy: How to screen positioning configuration while it is running?

Tags: synergy

I am using Synergy between two Macbooks (10.6 & 10.7).  Installed using Homebrew, version `1.3.6p2`.

I will sit in various places in relation to the secondary laptop, so sometimes I want the other screen to be on the right of my main screen and sometimes to the left.

How can I reconfigure this without shutting down Synergy, changing the config file, and restarting the server and the client?

Ideally it will be a terminal command so I can easily assign it to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just create different configuration files, and have a desktop shortcut/hotkey to run

```
synergyc --config {configfile}
```